# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am making a list view within a fragment. Following is my code:

> TitleQuote.java

```
package com.example.ishan.fragmentquote;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class QuoteList extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quote_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quote_list, container, false);
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            String quote = intent.getStringExtra(TitleQuote.INDEX);
            if(quote != null) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.quoteView);
                tv.setText("ishan");
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

> fragment_title_quote.xml

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleList"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

> fragment_quote_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ishan.fragmentquote.QuoteList$PlaceholderFragment"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/quoteView"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

when i build the project on android studio, everythin works fine i see no error/warnings. When i run this on an emulator/phone I get

> Unfortunately FragmentQuote has stopped.

the logcat error specifies :

> 2119-2119/com.example.ishan.fragmentquote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ishan.fragmentquote, PID: 2119
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

```
tv.setText("ishan");
```

Here your textview reference tv is getting null.

Comment: And can you explain why?

Comment: most probably, because of the following line: 
tools:context="com.example.ishan.fragmentquote.QuoteList$PlaceholderFragment"
in fragment_quote_list.xml ??

Comment: But I think the error comes from title activity specifically at the arraylist constructor, and tv.setText is part of another activity(quote view) which should start after I click on one of the title list items, but the app doesn't start up, it means the problem is in the first activity as the quote activity hasn't started yet

Comment: @IshanKhare so you think the problem is in a part of your code that you haven't posted?! why wouldn't you post the relevant code then? Maybe post the full stack trace too.

Comment: @ci_ the first activity is the titlequote.java file

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possible reason:

1. Where is onCreate method of your `QuoteList`Activity? So the context is null
2. I don't see you calling your `PlaceholderFragment?` Please note that `onCreateView` will be called only when you instantiate the `PlaceholderFragment`

If you have all those things in place then do share the complete code.